# Ubuntu automatically uninstalls R language packages when installing MongoDB 4.0.0

Tags: r, mongodb, installation

OS：
  Ubuntu 18.04.1

MongoDB version：
  4.0.0

R version：
  3.3.X

Question：
  After installing R language and dependency package through apt, when installing MongoDB according to the MongoDB official website document, the installed R language and dependency package will be automatically deleted.The same reason,Install MongoDB first, then install the R language, it will delete the already installed MongoDB.

Comment: R 3.3.X is not the normal version for Ubuntu 18.04. Where does that come from? Do you get any output concerning conflicting packages while packages are removed?

Comment: I install zsh have a question,so,i reinstall ubuntu.no problem at now.Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you are saying. Is your problem solved?